# 3 transactions sent all with a high fee and all still pending

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

This is a joke right now because I've sent 3 payments to different addresses with high fees and all of them are pending and won't confirm.

Answer (score 0):

there is a huge backlog of unconfirmed transactions, the biggest there has been. people are paying huge fees and still having to wait, just wait it out, you don't have a choice